# Aspnet Core. Remove the session of certain user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session

I have this code to access the current user state in session. But now, when I have new feature with blocking of user I need remove his active session if it's presented during block action. But in HttpContext I have access only to current user session, not specific. How I can remove/abandon/clear session of certain user?

```
public class HttpContextAccessorAdapter<TAccount> : IAccountAccessor<TAccount> where TAccount : AccountBase
    {
        private static string AccountSessionName = "Account";

        public HttpContextAccessorAdapter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            Accessor = accessor;
        }

        private IHttpContextAccessor Accessor { get; }

        public TAccount Account
        {
            get => Accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObject<TAccount>(AccountSessionName);
            set => Accessor.HttpContext.Session.SetObject(AccountSessionName, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to be the correct approach. When the blocked user makes any request to server you will detect that the user is blocked and delete his session.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi how you propose to detect that? During any request to obtain his state from db and check? I don't want that. It will be performance issue. I want check it during only login action. I believe that there should be present approach to terminate session of certain user. For example in google account you have feature to terminate your session on all devices

Comment: Are you using tokens to authentica? Maybe you can delete auth tokens and force the user to login again.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, no, I don't have them. I just authenticate user by his credentials and create session. And I lean only to user session in authorization processes.

So, how I can understand it, it's impossible to clear session of certain user? And I should use another approach any way?

Comment: I'm afraid that deleting other session does not makes a lot of sense... there might be a way but it sounds more like a hack. You could use some fast cache as Redis or similar to store information that you want to share across sessions.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, got it, thank you!